# How to resolve ambiguous match when chaining generated Jooq classes

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I have defined my models in JPA and am writing some queries for my application and I am using JOOQ generated classes to join all the tables together to check if the requested resources actually belong to the requesting user.

However, when I do this I get the following warning:

```
Ambiguous match found for ID. Both "alias_4548634"."ID" and "alias_47496750"."ID" match.

java.sql.SQLWarning: null                                                                                                                                       
        at org.jooq.impl.Fields.field(Fields.java:132) ~[jooq-3.11.10.jar:?]
... etc
```

This is my code

```
db.select(countField)
  .from(thing)
  .where(JThing.THING.thingBucket().bucket().organization().customer().ID.in(idList))
  .orderBy(countField)
```

This is the SQL it generates

```sql
SELECT 
  count(PUBLIC.THING.ID) AS count
FROM (
  PUBLIC.THING
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      PUBLIC.THING_BUCKET AS alias_72652126
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
          PUBLIC.BUCKET AS alias_4548634
            LEFT OUTER JOIN (
              PUBLIC.ORGANISATION AS alias_43016761
                LEFT OUTER JOIN PUBLIC.CUSTOMER AS alias_47496750
                ON alias_43016761.CUSTOMER_ID = alias_47496750.ID
            )
            ON alias_4548634.ORGANISATION_ID = alias_43016761.ID
        )
        ON alias_72652126.ID = alias_4548634.ID
    )
    ON PUBLIC.THING.THING_BUCKET_ID = alias_72652126.ID
  )
WHERE alias_47496750.ID IN (81353)
ORDER BY count
```

Given that JOOQ is generating the SQL I'd expect it to be able to understand it without throwing an error. What am I missing? How do I do configure/query/whatever to resolve the SQLWarning?

**UPDATE**

After playing around I've identified the source of the issue.

THING_BUCKET is sub-type of BUCKET so that THING_BUCKET.ID = BUCKET.ID

if I rewrite the query to I get the same results, but without the error

```
SELECT 
  count(PUBLIC.THING.ID) AS count
FROM (
  PUBLIC.THING
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
          PUBLIC.BUCKET AS alias_4548634
            LEFT OUTER JOIN (
              PUBLIC.ORGANISATION AS alias_43016761
                LEFT OUTER JOIN PUBLIC.CUSTOMER AS alias_47496750
                ON alias_43016761.CUSTOMER_ID = alias_47496750.ID
            )
            ON alias_4548634.ORGANISATION_ID = alias_43016761.ID
        )
    ON PUBLIC.THING.BUCKET_ID = alias_4548634.ID
  )
WHERE alias_47496750.ID IN (81353)
ORDER BY count
```

So what I would like to be able to do is go

```
db.select(countField)
  .from(thing)
  .where(JThing.THING.bucket().organization().customer().ID.in(idList))
  .orderBy(countField)
```

and join my THING directly to the BUCKET rather then the THING_BUCKET, but I do not know how to accomplish this with the generated classes.

Comment: Is this really the complete SQL statement generated by jOOQ or did you leave out something to simplify the example here? What's the full stack trace? What's the actual client code producing the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug that has been fixed in jOOQ 3.14, see [#8659](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8659), [#10603](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10603)

Answer (score 0):

From your description, looks like BUCKET and THINK_BUCKET being described as subtypes in the db level, are getting confused by the jooq generated classes.

A short term fix may be, to cut the hierarchical relation in the db level, regenerate and see what happens.