# jOOQ: How to resolve `Ambiguous match found for <column>` when joining across multiple tables?

Tags: jooq

The following jOOQ query spits out a SQL warning in my logs about: `Fields Ambiguous match found for id`

```
db.select(FORWARDED_MESSAGE.SES_MESSAGE_ID).
  from(FORWARDED_MESSAGE).
  where(
    FORWARDED_MESSAGE.FORWARDED.lt( DSL.currentTimestamp().subtract(
      FORWARDED_MESSAGE.mailMapping().mailKeyword().mailDomain().account().
        MESSAGE_RETENTION_DAYS ))).
  fetch(FORWARDED_MESSAGE.SES_MESSAGE_ID);
```

The SQL generated appears to be correct, but I don't want the warning polluting my logs (and I want to know if jOOQ is warning me about something important that I need to be aware of).

Some context about the schema tables:

- `forwarded_message` doesn't have a primary key
- `mail_domain` uses a natural PK named "domain"
- `mail_mapping`, `mail_keyword` and `account` all have a PK named `id`

I tried the following, but it fails saying `Key ambiguous between tables`:

```
db.select(FORWARDED_MESSAGE.SES_MESSAGE_ID).
  from(FORWARDED_MESSAGE).
    join(MAIL_MAPPING).onKey().
    join(MAIL_KEYWORD).onKey().
    join(MAIL_DOMAIN).onKey().
    join(ACCOUNT).onKey().
  where(
    FORWARDED_MESSAGE.FORWARDED.lt(
      DSL.currentTimestamp().subtract(ACCOUNT.MESSAGE_RETENTION_DAYS) )).
  fetch(FORWARDED_MESSAGE.SES_MESSAGE_ID);
```

jOOQ version is `3.13.4`, DB is postgres, using pgjdbc `42.2.14`.

**The Question**:
How do I resolve the `Fields Ambiguous match found` warning?

Note: this is not a dupe of [How to resolve ambiguous match when chaining generated Jooq classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55875983/924597) because that was about a sub-classing ambiguity - this question is about simple chaining of joins (across tables that do have duplicate PK columns).

Comment: Is there a stack trace with the warning? What's the DDL of the various table involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make the warning go away by re-writing the query to the `join().onKey()` style, but specifying the join foreign keys explicitly.

It's a bit verbose, but it seems to work:

```
db.select(FORWARDED_MESSAGE.SES_MESSAGE_ID).
  from(FORWARDED_MESSAGE).
    join(MAIL_MAPPING).
      onKey(Keys.FORWARDED_MESSAGE__FORWARDED_MESSAGE_MAIL_MAPPING_ID_FKEY).
    join(MAIL_KEYWORD).onKey(Keys.MAIL_MAPPING__MAIL_MAPPING_MAIL_KEYWORD_ID_FKEY).
    join(MAIL_DOMAIN).onKey(Keys.MAIL_KEYWORD__MAIL_KEYWORD_DOMAIN_FKEY).
    join(ACCOUNT).onKey(Keys.MAIL_DOMAIN__MAIL_DOMAIN_MAIL_DOMAIN_ACCOUNT_ID_FKEY).
  where(
    FORWARDED_MESSAGE.FORWARDED.lt(
      DSL.currentTimestamp().subtract(ACCOUNT.MESSAGE_RETENTION_DAYS) )).
  fetch(FORWARDED_MESSAGE.SES_MESSAGE_ID);
```

Not sure why this is much different from the `FORWARDED_MESSAGE.mailMapping()...account()` style.  But it works and the generated SQL is cleaner.